# How to "inject" in-memory SQLAlchemy sqlite3 database into Flask test_client?

Tags: python, flask, sqlite, sqlalchemy

I have a Flask application that I am using with SQLAlchemy. I don't want to use the Flask-SQLAlchemy extension. If I use a "real" database for testing and just set up environment variables that point to the test instance of the database, everything works well.

However, I've run into a problem if I want to point to an in-memory sqlite database for testing. In that case I can set up the data in my test, but when I use the test_client to execute a given route in my application, it can't find my database tables on the "server side" as it were - i.e. in the `hello.py` code shown further down. There must be a way to configure the test_client for this to work, but I can't seem to quite figure out how to do it.

Here are the snippets of code that may be relevant (db.py):

```
import os

from sqlalchemy import create_engine

from sqlalchemy.orm import scoped_session
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker

engine = create_engine(os.environ['SQLALCHEMY_URL'])

Session = scoped_session(sessionmaker(bind=engine))
```

Here I am setting up the scoped_session so that my database access will be thread-local.

The code that bootstraps my application (__init__.py):

```
from flask import Flask

from .db import Session

from .hello import hello_blueprint

app = Flask(__name__)
app.register_blueprint(hello_blueprint)

@app.teardown_appcontext
def cleanup(resp_or_exc):
    Session.remove()
```

Here  I'm setting up my app and registering the cleanup callback each time Flask pops the application context.

An example route in a blueprint (hello.py):

```
import json

from flask import Blueprint

from .db import Session

from .models import Message

hello_blueprint = Blueprint('hello', __name__)

@hello_blueprint.route('/messages')
def messages():
    values = Session.query(Message).all()

    results = []
    for value in values:
        results.append({ 'message': value.message })

    return (json.dumps(results), 200, { 'content_type': 'application/json' })
```

Here I'm using the scoped session to get some data from the database.

The definition of my `Message` model is just vanilla SQLAlchemy (models.py):

```
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base

from sqlalchemy import Column, Integer, String

Base = declarative_base()

class Message(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'messages'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    message = Column(String)

    def __repr__(self):
        return "<Message(message='%s')>" % (self.message)
```

Below is a very raw pytest unit test just to demonstrate the problem all in one place (test_hello.py):

```
import os 

import json

import pytest

import app

from .models import Message

@pytest.fixture
def client():
    client = app.app.test_client()

    return client

def test_hello(client):
    response = client.get('/')
    data = json.loads(response.data.decode('utf-8'))
    assert data == { 'message': "Hello friend!" }

def test_messages(client):
    with app.app.app_context():
        from sqlalchemy import create_engine
        from sqlalchemy import MetaData
        engine = create_engine('sqlite://')

        from .models import Base
        Base.metadata.create_all(engine)

        print('***metadata tables***')
        print(Base.metadata.tables.keys())

        from sqlalchemy.orm import scoped_session
        from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker

        Session = scoped_session(sessionmaker(bind=engine))

        message = Message(message='Hello there!')

        Session.add(message)
        Session.commit()

        values = Session.query(Message).all()

        results = []
        for value in values:
            results.append({ 'message': value.message })

        # This works, prints : [{"message": "Hello there!"}]
        print('*** result***')    
        print(json.dumps(results))

        # The code below doesn't work. Flask's app.py throws an exception
        # with the following at its root:
        # sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (sqlite3.OperationalError) no such table: 
        # messages [SQL: 'SELECT messages.id AS messages_id, messages.message AS messages_message, messages.new_field 
        # AS messages_new_field \nFROM messages'] (Background on this error at: http://sqlalche.me/e/e3q8)

        response = client.get('/messages')

        data =json.loads(response.data.decode('utf-8'))
        assert data == [{'message': 'Hello there!'}]
```

Comment: The correct string to create an in memory sqlite database is `:memory:` (See https://www.sqlite.org/inmemorydb.html). So maybe change your code to `create_engine('sqlite://:memory:')` and test. It should work if it was working with a normal file database earlier.

Comment: I tried it with `sqlite:////path/foo.db` and the test worked. However, with `sqlite:///:memory:` (note: 3 slashes, not 2),  I get the same 'no such table: messages' error. I assume it is because the memory context inside test_client is different from the regular memory context in the test itself. When both databases point to an external file or server, then the test works. However, for in-memory, I think I need to be able to somehow get the test_client context to see the in-memory database I set up in the test.

Comment: @PrahladYeri I'm not sure what I was doing wrong before - maybe with the way I was importing db-related modules - but now my test works without anything fancy or complicated. Thank you for you help!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite sure what I was doing wrong before, but I'm managed to get my test passing.

The modified version of the unit test is below (test_hello.py):

```
import os 

import json

import pytest

import app

from .db import engine
from .db import Session

from .models import Base
from .models import Message

@pytest.fixture
def client():
    Base.metadata.drop_all(engine)
    Base.metadata.create_all(engine)

    client = app.app.test_client()

    return client

def test_messages(client):
    message = Message(message='Hello there!')

    Session.add(message)
    Session.commit()

    response = client.get('/messages')

    data = json.loads(response.data.decode('utf-8'))
    assert data == [{'message': 'Hello there!'}]
```

Comment: How do you create the test engine here? Isn't the imported engine the production one?